# Update SQL row on mouse drag

Tags: jquery, sql

I have a php page which displays 3 columns from 3 different sql queries.  I am planning to apply drag and drop so that when I drag an item from one of the columns and drop it to the 2nd column it will change and update the sql entry to match that of the 2nd column results.

I have seen jquery draggable but am a noobie.  can anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#draggable").draggable();
$("#droppable").droppable({
  drop: function() { update_sql(); }
});
```

Comment: thanks for this. the drag and drop works. i got one problem though, how do i pass the item id to the droppable sql update? thanks.